# Compiling Chipmunk2D for Android using CMake

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, chipmunk

I want to use [Chipmunk2D](https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D) on Android.

In the sample `Chipmunk2D/android/Android.mk` they talk about using CMake to build Chipmunk2d for Android. As per the comment of the commit when this file was added suggests, I use [Android-CMake](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake) to build a static library and then link that in my Android project.

I invoke it like this:

```
cd Chipmunk2D/
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../android-cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DANDROID_NDK=~/ndk \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi" .
cmake --build .
```

Where Chipmunk2D is the folder containing the Chipmunk2D project, android-cmake contains Android-CMake, and ~/ndk is a symlink to android-ndk-r10.

It seems that the resulting .a is not compiled for Android, but for my local host because:

1. After compiling for my host and trying to compile for Android, CMake does nothing, i.e., it considers the targets completed.
2. When linking for Android ld complains "no archive symbol table (run ranlib)" and there are errors to undefined references to Chipmunk2D functions.

My current solution is to write an Android.mk similar to this one: https://gist.github.com/kristianlm/2628615 (warning, this is outdated). But then I'm reinventing how to build Chipmunk2D and I might be missing some build configurations from the project authors.

How do you build Chipmunk2D for Android using CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
Create a file called **Android.mk** in Chipmunk2D top level source directory like this. (Don't forget to change the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES path to match your location.)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

CHIPMUNK_SOURCES := src/chipmunk.c src/cpArbiter.c src/cpArray.c src/cpBBTree.c src/cpBody.c src/cpCollision.c src/cpConstraint.c src/cpDampedRotarySpring.c src/cpDampedSpring.c src/cpGearJoint.c src/cpGrooveJoint.c src/cpHashSet.c src/cpHastySpace.c src/cpMarch.c src/cpPinJoint.c src/cpPivotJoint.c src/cpPolyline.c src/cpPolyShape.c src/cpRatchetJoint.c src/cpRotaryLimitJoint.c src/cpShape.c src/cpSimpleMotor.c src/cpSlideJoint.c src/cpSpace.c src/cpSpaceComponent.c src/cpSpaceDebug.c src/cpSpaceHash.c src/cpSpaceQuery.c src/cpSpaceStep.c src/cpSpatialIndex.c src/cpSweep1D.c

LOCAL_MODULE    := chipmunk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CHIPMUNK_SOURCES)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(HOME)/src/Chipmunk2D/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DCP_USE_DOUBLES=0 -DCP_USE_CGPOINTS=0 -D__ARM_NEON__

LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then, in your own project, add this to **MyAwesomeGame/Android/jni/Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := chipmunk

...

$(call import-module,Chipmunk2D)
```

Also make sure that **NDK_MODULE_PATH** environment var can find your Chipmunk2D source directory. Mine includes $(HOME)/src as I have the chipmunk sources in $(HOME)/src/Chipmunk2D/

Now, Chipmunk static libraries will automatically be built if you build your own Android app:

```
$ cd MyAwesomeGame/Android
$ ndk-build
```